# Fix the following command so that it does search the home directory for files names README.md

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I am confused on these two answers I got. Question:

> Fix the following command so that it does search the home directory for files named `README.md`:
>
> ```
> find README.md ~
> ```

1. `find ~ -type f -name README.md` (the answer I gave but it's wrong, why?)
2. `find ~ -name README.md` (my professor's answer which is correct, how?)

Comment: Can't you ask the professor why your answer is wrong? You're paying them to teach you.

Comment: @Barmar she says this " If you use man on find, find needs a starting point and then a search pattern. The starting point is ~ (the user's home directory) README.md is the name of a file, and -name allows the pattern to be the base of a filename
"

Comment: @MosesO She's correct about that, but that doesn't explain why she thinks your answer is wrong. As long as the question specifically says to find **files**, I'd consider your answer more correct than hers (although in practice, hers would almost certainly be good enough).

Comment: @Moses O The problem that I'm seeing here is that you have made the _assumption_ that what has been looked for is regular files. Assumptions, however, are the first step toward an error. So if someone asks for files without further qualifiers, your best bet would be to interpret "file" as "any entity that has an entry in a directory", and from that vantage point, your prof's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are correct. However, your answer is more appropriate if the question specifically asks to find regular files.

1. The first command: `find ~ -type f -name README.md` specifically searches for regular files (not directories or other types of files) named "README.md" in the home directory.
2. The second command: `find ~ -name README.md` searches for any file or directory named "README.md" in the home directory, including regular files, directories, symbolic links, etc.